# exchanging each occurence with a different string in ruby

Tags: ruby, string, gsub

I have an array of strings in a proper order. I would like to do something like this:

```
text.gsub!(/my_pattern/, array[i++])
```

In other words - I'd like to exchange the first occurence of my_pattern with array[0], the second one with array[1], etc. Any hints?

Comment: I presume you mean that, for each `i = 0,1,2...`, the `i`th matched string is to be replaced with `array[i]`.

Comment: Yes, that's excatly what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`String#gsub!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-gsub-21) accepts an optional block. The return value of the block is used as a replacement string.

Using with [`Enumerable#each_with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index):

```
array = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'forth', 'fifth']
text = 'my_pattern, my_pattern, my_pattern, my_pattern'
text.gsub!(/my_pattern/).each_with_index { |_, i| array[i] }
# => "first, second, third, forth"
```

Comment: @zenn1337, Welcome to Stack Overflow! There are people who have tried to answer your question. If this helped you, you can tell the community so by [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5235) that was most useful for you.

Comment: ...yes, by all means, but there is no rush to do so. Some posters wait several hours, sometimes days, before selecting an answer, in part because they do not wish to discourage the posting of additional, possibly better, answers.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

```
replacements = array.dup
text.gsub!(/my_pattern/) { |_| replacements.shift || 'no replacements left' }
```

Duplicate the array with `array.dup` first, because `shift` modifies the array. If there are more matches than elements in the array then the pattern is replaced with the string `no replacements left`. If you want to keep matches untouched if there are no elements left in the array, just to this:

```
text.gsub!(/my_pattern/) { |match| replacements.shift || match }
```

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
array = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'forth', 'fifth']
text = 'my_pattern, my_pattern, my_pattern, my_pattern'

enum = array.to_enum
text.gsub!(/my_pattern/) { enum.next }
  #=> "first, second, third, forth"
text
  #=> "first, second, third, forth"
```

[Enumerator#next](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) will raise a `StopIterator` exception if invoked when the end of the array has been reached (i.e., if there are more strings to be replaced than there are elements of `arr`).  If you are concerned about that possibility, you will need to `rescue` the exception in the block and handle it appropriately.